# ¿Es recomendable tener un ID largo en la BD?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

soy nuevo en esto y nose si es recomendable tener un ID largo, por ejemplo al momento de crear un correlativo lo normal seria esto `Tabla01(tabla_id, correlativo) - Tabla01(01,20200616)`.
Pero puedo poner el correlativo como ID o afectaría en algo al rendimiento de la BD

Comment: Saludos. Lo que agiliza es tener indexada la columna(s), principalmente si esta(s) es/son de búsquedas (en: WHERE, INNER ...). Como planteas TABLA01 si es un tipo catálogo y controlaras "correlativo" no se inserte otro nuevo registro con valor similar puede ser. Considere que quiere modificar una fila, si no hay al menos una columna o conjunto de columnas que identifique 1 registro de los demás puede terminar afectando varias.

Answer (score 4):

No responderé a si es mejor o no, para evitar caer en el punto de las *opiniones* en su lugar mencionaré aspectos relevantes:

- Un `id` generalmente declarado como `INT` o `BIGINT` puede alcanzar una longitud máxima de: **2<sup>64</sup>-1** entonces dudo lo alcances a superar.
- Por otro lado un valor que se declare como `id` es generalmente también aquel que se considera como *llave primaria* y por ende no deberá repetirse.

  - En este punto entonces deberías verificar si el correlativo no tendría en algún momento un valor repetido
- Quizás la forma mas simple es que desde el inicio:

  - Identifica que columnas vas a ocupar para hacer tus búsquedas y con base en ello crear índices de las mismas para acelerar las búsquedas de los mismos
  - Considera que MySQL o MariaDB (por que no se de los demás) ya una columna declarada como llave primaria se optimiza e indexa para acelerar las búsquedas
- El rendimiento de tus consultas depende de mas factores que el solo hecho de una llave primaria (*que si también es relevante*), por eso menciono mas arriba el punto declarar como índices todas aquellas columnas que sepas usarás para realizar tus consultas.
- Por otro lado si la columna de correlativo no implica operaciones matemáticas para dichos valores y para evitar pérdida de datos será mas seguro almacenarlo como un *string* y nuevamente indexarlo

**Referencias**

- [MySQL tipos de datos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)
- [llaves primarias en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/primary-key-optimization.html)
- [índices en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Muy bien,  la respondiste sin caer en opiniones y ademas es util,  +1.

Comment: La definición de los índices, simples o compuestos, es más que definir "como índices" unas u otras columnas. Es lo único que añadiría a tu respuesta.

Comment: @Alfabravo adelante compañero, la respuesta esta abierta a ediciones que la mejoren

Comment: Gracias, tendré en cuenta los puntos distes y mejorar mis tablas

Comment: Ahora que lo veo, esto es una pregunta basada en opiniones no? Como pasa el tiempo jejej